# Alternating Series: Intervals

Tags: calculus

can you take a look at the link below where I uploaded a math problem solved by my professor. In part d), how did he arrive to -0.234? The -0.242 is 0.008 + that 0.234, but both intervals are negative. Both interval numbers have confused me, I'd appreciate it if someone could clarify. I would ask him but it's the weekend and I need to understand before I proceed with the problem.

Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are evaluating the sum up to the first 10 terms and we obtain $-0.2346$ since the next term is negative we are over estimating the sum and the lower bound is obtained adding the $11^{th}$ term which leads to $-0.2421$.

The key fact is that the upper sum (even terms) is decreasing and the lower sum (odd terms) is increasing that is for any $n$

$$S_{2}\le S_{4} \le \ldots \le S_{2n}\le S_{\infty} \le S_{2n-1} \le \ldots \le S_{3}\le S_{1}$$

Comment: Got it. Thank you both!!